# CSS stylesheet issue. Responsive Nav bar font color not responding

Tags: php, css, menu, navigation

I'm working on a responsive layout and it has two different menu layouts, standard and mobile.           I can't seem to get the font color to change on the current page link in the main(2nd) navigation menu. I can set the back ground of the current/active page, and it works in both menus; however when I change the font/link color it only changes in the mobile menu. I have searched and can't seem to find the reason this happens or a solution.

Here's the page: http://www.newmanlandscaping.com/index2.php

Here's the style sheet: http://www.newmanlandscaping.com/nlstyle.css

Thanks for looking,
Töm

```
#home .home a:link, #home .home a:visited,#home .home a:hover, #home .home a:active,  
#contact .contact a:link, #contact .contact a:visited, #contact .contact a:hover,                           #contact .contact a:active,
#photos .photos a:link, #photos .photos a:visited, #photos .photos a:hover, #photos     .photos a:active, 
#services .services a:link, #services .services a:visited, #services .services a:hover,     #services .services a:active{  <br>


font-weight: bold;
background-color: green; /*This changes the background link color to display the current page. Works in both menus. */
color: white;      /* This changes the link font color of the current page in the menu. This only changes on the mobile menu. */
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: which color you have try to apply? Right now it is `ffff00`.

Comment: It's set to white see mobile menut curent page link color.

Comment: see below:
#home .home a:link, #home .home a:visited,#home .home a:hover, #home .home a:active,
#contact .contact a:link, #contact .contact a:visited, #contact .contact a:hover, #contact .contact a:active,
#photos .photos a:link,
<br>
background-color: green; /*This changes the background link color to display the current page. Works in both menus. */
 color: white;      /* This changes the link font color of the current page in the menu. This only changes on the mobile menu. */

Answer (score 1):

Use "!important" keyword so that it will not override with others.

```
#home .home a:link, #home .home a:visited, #home .home a:hover, #home .home a:active, #home .home .mainheader nav a:link, #home .home .mainheader nav a:visited, #home .home .mainheader nav a:hover, #home .home .mainheader nav a:active, #contact .contact a:link, #contact .contact a:visited, #contact .contact a:hover, #contact .contact a:active, #photos .photos a:link, #photos .photos a:visited, #photos .photos a:hover, #photos .photos a:active, #services .services a:link, #services .services a:visited, #services .services a:hover, #services .services a:active
{
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: green; /*This changes the background link color to display the current page. Works in both menus. */
 color: white !important;      /* This changes the link font color of the current page in the menu. This only changes on the mobile menu. */
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```